# WCF C# - Need to send multiple response to client for a single request

Tags: c#, wcf

Based on the single request invoke, Need to send multiple responses on timely basis to single client. The binding is Netnamedpipe.

I couldn't find anything.

Comment: This needs way more detail to be reasonable answerable. You're 100% sure none of these could get you started: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwcf%5D+netnamedpipe+ ? At a minimum provide the client interface and the service interface so it is clear what "multiple response" means.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use NetNamedPipeBinding, see if [Large Data and Streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/large-data-and-streaming?redirectedfrom=MSDN) fit your requirements.